# how to list all EXPO release-channel?

Tags: react-native, expo

Where can I find a list of all release channels for an EXPO app?

The last developer left and we don't know the --release-channel in use. Is there any way to find out the --release-channel's there were about 6 or 7 we need to find out

```
exp publish --release-channel <your-channel>
```

Answer (score 23):

You can see everything that you’ve published with `expo publish:history`

Also you can filter by platform:

`expo publish:history --platform ios`

`expo publish:history --platform android`

Documentation: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/distribution/advanced-release-channels

Comment: There's only 5 elements in the list, do you know if it's possible to show the complete list ?

Comment: "expo publish:history --count 100"  (--count = Number of logs to view, maximum 100, default 5.)